# DiscordJS V12 Enabling & Disabling Events With A Command

Tags: events, discord.js, event-handling

I would like to make a command that enables or disables the `unknown command event` and is automatically disabled how would i go about doing this?

The Event:

```
    return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
      .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon)
      .setTitle(`❌ Unkown command, try: **\`${prefix}help\`**`)
      .setDescription(`.setup has a list of info you might need`)
    ).then(msg=>msg.delete({timeout: 5000}).catch(e=>console.log("Couldn't Delete".gray)));
```

Comment: What do you mean by enable and disabling?

Comment: A command that enables and disables an event so when i say do !enable-event it will enable the event that tells you if a command is incorrect but if i do !disable-event it wont say anything when typing an incorrect event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to be able to save a variable somewhere (database, json file, etc). I prefer databases but that is my personal preference. So my answer will be based on saving it to a database. It may not be your choice but it can work.

```js
const con = require('./database.js')

// if doing it as a message command with a prefix

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
// set up command recognition here

    if (command === 'enable-event') {
        con.query(`UPDATE database_name SET event = 'enabled' WHERE event_name = 'invalid'`)
    } else if (command === 'disable-event') {
        con.query(`UPDATE database_name SET event = 'disabled' WHERE event_name = 'invalid'`)
    }

    if (!command) {
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM database_name WHERE event_name = 'invalid'`, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err
            const status = rows[0].event

            if (status === 'enabled') {
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
                    .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon)
                    .setTitle(`❌ Unkown command, try: **\`${prefix}help\`**`)
                    .setDescription(`.setup has a list of info you might need`)

                return message.channel.send({
                    embeds: [embed]
                }).then((msg) => {
                      msg.delete({
                          timeout: 5000
                      })
                  }).catch(e => 
                        console.log("Couldn't Delete".gray)
                    )
            } else {
            return
            }
        })
    }
})
```